# Python: find the maximum of a series (produced from a pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I do not know why I can't find the maximum of the series. Could someone help? It is produced from a pandas dataframe

```
temp
Out[190]: 
0               0
1       0.0197017
2       0.0183603
3       0.0483337
4       0.0136385

8187    0.0800631
8188    0.0433753
8189    0.0673788
8190    0.0511651
8191    0.0811448
Name: adjr2, Length: 8192, dtype: object

type(temp)
Out[191]: pandas.core.series.Series

temp.idxmax(axis = 1 , skipna=True)
```

This gives an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-192-21f0a425e80d>", line 1, in <module>
    temp.idxmax(axis = 1 , skipna=True)

  File "/Users/miao/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2277, in idxmax
    i = nanops.nanargmax(com.values_from_object(self), skipna=skipna)

  File "/Users/miao/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py", line 67, in _f
    raise TypeError(msg.format(name=f.__name__.replace("nan", "")))

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

Comment: Cast to numeric first. You have an object dtype column

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Series` to numeric by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
temp.astype(float).idxmax(axis = 1 , skipna=True)
```

Or if some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert them to missing values `NaN`s:

```
pd.to_numeric(temp, errors='coerce').idxmax(axis = 1 , skipna=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the aggregation function in pandas (such as max) doesn't support operation on none-numeric types (as `string` or `object`). You could try converting your data to a numeric type (which will also improve performance on big datasets).

You can use `temp.astype` to convert the series.

```py
In [47]: s
Out[47]:
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [48]: s.astype(float)
Out[48]:
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [50]: s.astype(float).idxmax()
Out[50]: 'c'
```